# Why does my code provide an error when I try getting it to speak what it recognized?

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, speech, pyttsx

I'm experimenting with speech on Python3, I'm very new with python and I have scoured all of the internet to understand what's wrong with my code, when I run the code I get the error you can see below. Please help me understand what's happening better.

Here is my code:

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import time
import pyttsx3

r = sr.Recognizer()

with sr.Microphone() as mic:
    print("Say something")
    audio = r.listen(mic)
    print("Recording Stopped")
r.recognize_google(audio)






if r.recognize_google(audio) == "I'm pretty" or r.recognize_google(audio) == "I am pretty" :
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say("You said: I'm Ugly")
    engine.runAndWait()
else:
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
    engine.say("You said: " + r.recognize_google(audio))
    engine.runAndWait()
```

Here is the error message:

```
Last login: Sat Feb 16 18:03:26 on ttys002
ErenUcar-3:~ eucar$  python /Users/eucar/.atom/packages/atom-python-run/lib/../cp/main.py --pause -- python3 /Users/eucar/Documents/Testing/noob.py


Say something
Recording Stopped
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 44, in init
    eng = _activeEngines[driverName]
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/weakref.py", line 137, in __getitem__
    o = self.data[key]()
KeyError: None

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/eucar/Documents/Testing/noob.py", line 23, in <module>
    engine = pyttsx3.init()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyttsx3/__init__.py", line 46, in init
    eng = Engine(driverName, debug)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyttsx3/engine.py", line 52, in __init__
    self.proxy = driver.DriverProxy(weakref.proxy(self), driverName, debug)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyttsx3/driver.py", line 75, in __init__
    self._module = importlib.import_module(name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pyttsx3/drivers/nsss.py", line 2, in <module>
    from Foundation import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'Foundation'

Process returned 1 (0x1)    execution time : 10.702 s
Close this window to continue...
ErenUcar-3:~ eucar$
```

Comment: Can you please provide more details about what exactly you want to achieve?

Comment: @Julia I want someone to say something, and then I want the program to output what is being said in the form of speech.